# issue with asp.net listview paging in mozilla

Tags: asp.net, listview, paging, mozilla

I have code like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When I click on paging in datapager, first the IsPostBack condition is skipped since it is a postback and then control moves to listItems_PagePropertiesChanging() event.
   After executing this event, the control goes to page_Load again and gets inside the  if(!IsPostBack) condition.

This is happening only in Mozilla 3.0.14, but not in IE 7.0.

Anyone please give me a solution ASAP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your code issuing a redirect?

Comment: no, my code doesn't issue a redirect

Comment: Is your datapager inside another user control??